# GmailApp.sendEmail() From Plus Address

Tags: gmail

Question: Is there a way to override the account email address and replace it with a plus address on the same account?

I'm using the GmailApp.sendEmail() method in Google Apps.

The account e-mail address is a non-plus (obviously) address, but I use several plus addresses to filter messages into categories.

When I send a message with sendEmail(), it uses the main account address and it does not appear that there is a way to change this for a script.

While I can set the "name" for the account, I'd like to set the from address to a plus version of the account address.

(I remember running into this same issue with the Calendar user interface.)

So, I also tried setting a replyTo address using the advanced parameters. (This is not the way I'd prefer to do it.)

The replyTo parameter obviously accepts the address and the message that is sent contains the reply-to header. I've include the header lines below with 'example' replacing the account address.

```
Delivered-To: example+test@gmail.com

Reply-To: Richard Michael <example+pch@gmail.com>

From: Richard Michael <example@gmail.com>
To: example+test@gmail.com
```

When I use the Reply button in Gmail, however, the 'To' address that loads in the form is example+test@gmail.com which is neither of the possibilities I would expect. (It should be the Reply-to or, at worst, the From address.) The From address in the reply form is example@gmail.com, which is expected (but also the reason I want to 'send' from a plus address).

I've repeated this several times with the same result.

Of course, Gmail also allows you to 'send' from foreign accounts as well in the user interface after you've performed a validation check. So, you can't send from those addresses either.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the parameter from: in the methode [GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#sendEmail).

Example

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('example@exapmle.com', 'Testmail', 'Hello Richard',
                        {name: 'Richard Michel', from: 'example+pch@gmail.com',});
```

I'm using [Mail Merge HD](http://www.labnol.org/internet/personalized-mail-merge-in-gmail/20981/) and i edited the code a little.

In function fnMailmerge() i added the lines

```
  top_panel.add(myapp.createLabel("Please select your alias"));
  var lf = myapp.createListBox(false).setWidth(250).setName('from').addItem("Select aliases...").setVisibleItemCount(1);

  for (var i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
   lf.addItem(aliases[i]);
  }

  top_panel.add(lf);
```

, added the last statement to this line (in the same function)

```
var handler = myapp.createServerClickHandler('startMailMerge').addCallbackElement(lb).addCallbackElement(name_box).addCallbackElement(bcc_box).addCallbackElement(lf);
```

and finaly editet the function Gmail.sendEmail

```
 GmailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText,
                        {name: e.parameter.name, attachments: attachments, htmlBody: emailText, cc: cc, bcc: bcc, inlineImages: inlineImages, from: e.parameter.from,});
```

This adds a dropdown list to the Mail Menu, where you can chose from your registered Aliases.