# Authorise sendMail() to send from current user from forms addon

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a Forms addon script that is triggered by `onFormSubmit`. It takes all the filled in answers, creates a PDF file and mails it to a specific user (based on one of the answers).

Right now, the MailApp.sendMail() function is used to send the email. However, all emails are sent from my own account (=the developer), instead of from the account of the current user who is filling out the form.

I've tried a few things:

- **Deploy as web app** - This allowed me to select "run as current user", but the URL I get from the deployed web app gives an error (`sorry, unable to open this file at present`). Most likely because this isn't a real web app (there's no GUI)?
- **Deploy as forms add-on** - Upon pressing "publish", I get an error at the top: `Chrome Web Store system error, please try again later` with no additional information. (Is this maybe related to a domain-setting about being allowed to deploy scripts?)

So obviously there are some permission issues going on here. What I want is actually really simple: A script that is attached to a single Form (created by me), that asks a user for permission to send out an email on his behalf. The script/form should only be available to users from my domain, and the emails will only be sent to users from my domain.

Comment: If you are deploying google script as web app, make sure your script comply with the rules of web app. see : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Yeah, it's not really a web-app; there's no GUI. I just tried the option because at least that option gave me the "run as:" option.

Comment: you can switch to gmailApp which has a "from parameter" https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options

Maybe if you capture the logged account alias and add it in the from parameter you can reach what you're looking for

here is a good example of gmailApp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443014/gmailapp-sendemail-from-plus-address

Comment: For the GMailApp, you can only chose "from" addresses that are aliases of the authorised user. So the same problem there: If the app is authorised on my account, it won't be the visiting user's account.